# How to start at the nth file of specific extension in the directory

Tags: shell-script

I need to start execution at the nth ".pdf" file, where the start point is an argument. As we call `rename.sh 2`, it should start executing from the second file

```
n=0
for file in *.pdf; do
   while [ $n -le $count ]; do
     filename=${file%$n*}.txt
     n=$(($n+1))
     echo $filename
   done
done
```

where "count" is the number of .pdf files in the directory. The files in the directory are as follows `one1.pdf`, `two2.pdf`, `three3.pdf`, etc.

Comment: You're not changing `$n` or `$count` inside the `while` loop, so it will never change, and your `file=` expression is incorrect.

Comment: You are changing the `file` variable used in your for loop inside the loop. Confusing at best and likely an error. You are also looping over pdf files but inside the loop you look at txt files. Again, confusing.

Comment: actually, the files will be changed to `one.txt`, `two.txt` and `three.txt`
but I want a way to start changing from "two2.pdf" upward

Comment: @doneal24 the confusion has been solved

Comment: You do realize that `two.pdf`  will be the third file if you have only three files. If you add a fourth then `four.pdf` will be the second file in the list. If you have resolved the confusion, please update the question with the changes.

Comment: The above code just replaces names of files ending with "n.pdf" to files ending with ".txt" so if even the renamed files are added in the directory, it will not cause harm

Comment: You never increment `n` so you're in an infinite loop. You are also matching on `n` being the last character before the extension but the filenames include the extension. The test winds up being against `one.pdf.1*` which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: yeah true, Thanks
The main question still remains how to make use of a start point

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved it. It works only for files having the same base name before the interger (eg. text1.pdf, text2.pdf, text3.pdf). If n is different from start, We need to increment n untill it is equal to the required start point

```
#!/bin/sh

start=$1
n=0
count=$(find . -type f -name "*.ppm" | wc -l)
for file in *.pdf; do
   if [ $n -eq "$start" ]; then
       while [ $n -le $count ]; do
          filename=${file%"$n"*}.txt
          n=$((n+1))
          start=$((start+1))
          echo "conversion of" $file to $filename
          break
       done
   else
       n=$((n+1))
   fi
done
```

Comment: You don't need to prefix shell variables with a `$` inside of a `$(())`. Also, if variables `$n` and `$start` are supposed to hold numerical values, `-eq` should be used instead of a string comparison `=`. The expansion `${file%$n*}` also requires quoting if `$n` is to be expanded instead of treated like a regular expression. In general, I recommend using shellcheck utility or https://shellcheck.net to lint scripts.

Comment: Yesir!, thank you very much, that's a great update.